# R cumulative sum by variable with re-set

Tags: r, variables, dplyr, statistics

I am a part time R user and i am looking for some advice in regards to the below query:

I am attempting to create an SPC graph that will step up and or step down based on a number of data points falling above / below the mean. I understand that there are tried and tested R packages out there such as qcc that will produce a nice SPC graph rather easily but unfortunately it does not appear do what we want, which is to show a step up or step down on the control limits based on 8 points being under or over. (at least from what I could see).

My initial thoughts after manually creating the Average and the control limits was to create a variable that would assign a TRUE or FALSE value when the data was under or over the limit, then create a running count of the TRUE / FALSE values, using the runner package, followed by another variable that would reset the running count when >= 9. What I am finding is that the count resets to 1 when the running count hits 9, but will not re calculate as expected until the variable changes again between TRUE / FALSE. Please see the below code and data output as an example:

```
 make count of n above and below the mean

    dat4 = dat4 %>% 
       group_by(`Dept`) %>% 
       mutate(Count = case_when(n > Mean ~ TRUE, 
                                n < Mean ~ FALSE))

create a running count of the number of times n moves above / below the mean

        dat4 = dat4 %>%
      group_by(`Dept`) %>%
      mutate(run = streak_run(Count))

 reset the run when it reaches 8 then start over again for each Dept

dat4 = dat4 %>%
  group_by(`Dept`, run) %>%
  mutate(runreset = case_when(run >= 9 ~ streak_run(run),
                              run < 9 ~ run))
```

Please note that the data is stored in a dataframe format (the below formatting is just so that it should make it easier for you guys to read as an example):

```
Count <- c(F, T, T, T, T, T, T, T, T, T, T, T, F, F, T)
run <- c(1,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,1,2,1)
runreset <- c(1,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,**8,1,1,1**,1,2,1)
```

What I would expect to see is it to begin to repeat the count when it passes 8:

```
runreset <- c(1,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,**8,1,2,3**,1,2,1)
```

Any ideas on how I could go about trying to resolve this would be much appreciated, of course the next step after this would be to re calculate the control limits based on when the runreset passes 8 for each Dept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There could be multiple ways to achieve this, one way would be to use `%%` to get remainder when `run > 8` so that the count automatically initialises after `run > 8`.

```
transform(df, runans = ifelse(run > 8, run %% 8, run))

#   Count run runreset runans
#1  FALSE   1        1      1
#2   TRUE   1        1      1
#3   TRUE   2        2      2
#4   TRUE   3        3      3
#5   TRUE   4        4      4
#6   TRUE   5        5      5
#7   TRUE   6        6      6
#8   TRUE   7        7      7
#9   TRUE   8        8      8
#10  TRUE   9        1      1
#11  TRUE  10        1      2
#12  TRUE  11        1      3
#13 FALSE   1        1      1
#14 FALSE   2        2      2
#15  TRUE   1        1      1
```

If you want to apply this by group

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(Dept) %>% mutate(runans = ifelse(run > 8, run %% 8, run))
```

**data**

```
Count <- c(F, T, T, T, T, T, T, T, T, T, T, T, F, F, T)
run <- c(1,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,1,2,1)
runreset <- c(1,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,1,1,1,1,2,1)
df <- data.frame(Count, run, runreset)
```

Comment: Thank you so much Ronak I did not know about that %% sign or its use :), very informative. Just for info, I had to make a slight adjustment to the code as after the first reset on 8 it would then reset at 7 if for example there was a long run of 16 or more (TRUE / FALSE) in a row `run %% 9`